# How to get DOM node depth with respect to Element?

Tags: php, dom

How can I get depth of a DOM node with respect to HTML elements? (that is HTML tags as children, not text node).

For Example :

```
<div> // root node
  here is my text node // but it wont be considered in level increment
   <p> // level 1
      <label>  // level 2
             here is another text node
      </label>
   </p>
</div>
```

This should return 2.

I have tried this, but it isn't functional:

```
function getDepth($node, $depth) {

foreach ($node->childNodes as $child):
    if($child->nodeType === 1):
        $depth++;
    endif;
    if ($node->childNodes):
        getDepth($child, $depth);
    endif;
endforeach;

return $depth;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Walk the tree upwards. Something like this should do (untested):

```
function getDepth($node)
{
    $depth = -1;

    // Increase depth until we reach the root (root has depth 0)
    while ($node != null)
    {
        $depth++;

        // Move to parent node
        $node = $node->parentNode;
    }

    return $depth;
}
```

Comment: Can you please expand your answer a little more by telling me how would i get to the leaf of any node ?

Comment: What do you mean? This function returns the depth of the node you pass it by walking the ancestry tree back to the root. No leaves involved.

Comment: And how it will care of ELEMENTS ? Mean incrementing the depth only if the child is ELEMENT type = 3 ?

Comment: You probably mean element type 1. This function doesn't have to check the element type because parent nodes can *never* be anything else than element nodes.

Comment: yes i meant type 1. I have tested your function but it returns 3 in this case while it should have returned 2 instead for this case : 

        <div>
            <h2>
                h2 tag- content
            </h2>
            End of the segment text
            <b>Here is a bold tag</b>
        </div>

Comment: also elements like span or label inside text element ain't suppose to be its child ?

Comment: It is unclear how you are testing the function, please try to think a while about the solution I'm offering you. Also, no, text nodes cannot have children.

Comment: i am passing node to the function and it returns depth = 3 from your function. COntents of the node i passed to it are this so you may also give it a try and suggest if i am doing it wrong:
<div> <h2> h2 tag- content </h2> End of the segment text <b>Here is a bold tag</b> </div>

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24683/discussion-between-atif-and-cicada)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend this:

```
function findNodeLevel($node) { // $node is a DOMNode 
    $xpath = explode('/', $node->getNodePath());
    return count($xpath);
}
```